# create a personalized 404 error page in php in localhost

Tags: php, .htaccess, localhost, http-status-code-404

I want to create a personalized `404 error page` in php , I want to it works in localhost, as you know the localhost does not have .htaccess file !

Comment: It doesn't? My Apache has. `=]`

Comment: where ? I use wampserver

Comment: Actually, it's in the sites' folders. Nothing prevents you from creating one there.

Comment: could you explain much please ? How I can create 404 error page ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a .htaccess file in your localhost. Simply make sure it is in the root directory of your web server (I believe in WAMP, it's the www folder). In XAMPP, it's the htdocs folder

Comment: Is it also possible to create different 404 pages for different websites? For example, I have a 404 page costumed for website 1 (stored in ..\wamp\www\web1\ or ..\htdocs\web1) and another 404 page costumed for website 2 (stored in ..\wamp\www\web2\ or ..\htdocs\web2).

Answer (score 4):

You can create a .htaccess file in your localhost. Simply make sure it is in the root directory of your web server (I believe in WAMP, it's the *www* folder). In XAMPP, it's the *htdocs* folder

Then in your .htaccess file, you simply need something along the lines of:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /path/to/error/404/page
```

Comment: I can not create .htaccess file,the windows got error that `you must type a file name`

Comment: Ugly hack: type `type nul>.htaccess` in the command prompt and you have a blank `.htaccess` file. It's easier to copypaste an existing one usually.

Comment: You can also create a file (such as a txt file), and use a program such as FileZilla (An FTP Client).
You can then edit that file name / extension to .htaccess and Windows will not complain.

Comment: @JavadYousefi Here's the link to an working and commented [`.htaccess`](http://temp-share.com/show/dPf3mCuHW). Put it in the `www`/`htdocs` folder and edit it with notepad to set the path correctly as David answered.

Comment: Eh, Firefox and Chrome won't let me save it like that, oh well, you'll have to rename it with FileZilla or the Prompt. Or, a [rar'ed](http://temp-share.com/show/Pf3Y665K2) file should allow you to extract.

Comment: :D Thanks my friends, dear Fabrício Matté please zip the .htaccess file and then send it for me , or upload it.My email Address : Javad.y1 at Gmail.com